# How to change the annotation of data resulted by Yolov8?

Tags: data-annotations, yolov8

I have a huge number of images that have human.
after a ran Yolov8 on them, all resulted labels are class 0 "person"
I want to change to 3 classes class 0 "man", class 1 "woman", class 2 "child" based on the image.

how can I do this in easiest way ?

example the resulted label file:
0 0.912747 0.641636 0.173486 0.701598
0 0.711514 0.368986 0.127007 0.269725
0 0.353645 0.612958 0.214726 0.653104
0 0.294899 0.279542 0.154637 0.497855

I want to change it to:
1 0.912747 0.641636 0.173486 0.701598
0 0.711514 0.368986 0.127007 0.269725
2 0.353645 0.612958 0.214726 0.653104
0 0.294899 0.279542 0.154637 0.497855

I have tried to do it manually, but It's time consuming.
and I'm thinking of using ChatGPT 4.0

Thanks for help in advance.